# Laravel, How to use two database tables in the same view

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a menu view and settings view. In the menu view, you can add menu categories and in the settings, you can change name, bio, and profile picture. I want to combine all that menu view. I can easily add and update forms from settings but can't add user data from the database to MenuController.

I am new to coding and at this point I have no idea what am I doing.

Here is my MenuController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Menu;
use App\Models\User;

class MenuController extends Controller
{
    public function index(User $user)
    {
        $menus = Auth::user()->menus()
        ->get();

        $name = $user->name;
        $tittle = $user->tittle;
        $bio = $user->bio;
        $bioShow = $user->bio_show;
        $backgroundColor = $user->background_color;
        $buttonBorderRadius = $user->button_border_radius;
        $buttonTextColor = $user->button_text_color;
        $buttonColor = $user->button_color;
        $textColor = $user->text_color;
        $vcardShow = $user->vcard_show;

        return view('menus.index', [

            'menus' => $menus,
            'user' => $user,
            'name' => $name,
            'tittle' => $tittle,
            'bio' => $bio,
            'bioShow' => $bioShow,
            'backgroundColor' => $backgroundColor,
            'buttonBorderRadius' => $buttonBorderRadius,
            'buttonTextColor' => $buttonTextColor,
            'buttonColor' => $buttonColor,
            'textColor' => $textColor,
            'vcardShow' => $vcardShow,
        ]);
        
    }

There is more code below but it's not relevant
```

It seems like I loaded the User model successfully since I have no errors, but in my view, it won't show any username, maybe because it's not specified which user should it show?

Here is the relevant view code where I want to see user's name displayed in h1, but nothing shows.

```
    <div class="content">
        <div class="head">
            <h1>Restaurant Menu</h1>
            <a href="/dashboard/qrcode"><button class="qrcode"><h1>QR Code</h1><i class='bx bx-qr-scan'></i></button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="about_me">
        </div>
        <h1>User: {{ $user->name }}</h1>
        @foreach($menus as $menu)
            <div class="link">
                <a href="/dashboard/menu/{{ $menu->id }}">
                    <button class="edit">
                        <div class="info">
                            <div class="left">
                                <div class="img-border">
                                    <p class="url">{{ $menu->price }}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text">
                                    <div class="indicate">
                                        <div class="indicator" style="background-color: {{ $menu->indicator }};"></div>
                                        <p class="name">{{ $menu->name }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="url">{{ $menu->description }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <i class='bx bx-chevron-right'></i>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>
        @endforeach
        <div class="add_link">
            <a href="/dashboard/menu/new"><button><i class='bx bx-plus'></i></button></a>
            <p>Add New Link</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: are you passing the User to the route of Menu?? I mean there is index(User $user) what does $user return ..

Comment: Yes, it goes to the route of Menu. I tried connecting User model using (User, $user) thinking it will allow me to fetch data from user table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it looks like there are 2 variables that are most important...

User and Menus;

I looks like the User details is of the logged in User and not of any other user then u can change it to

```
$user = Auth::user();
$menus = $menus = Auth::user()->menus()->get();

return view('menus.index', compact('menus', 'user'));
```

pass the whole object to the view...

if you would want to debug what values are being sent to view in user and menus

```
return [
    'user' => $user,
    'menus' => $menus,
];
```

Now in view you can directly use the user object

```
{{ $user->name }} // Print User name
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed, however, there was one `)` missing in `return view('menus.index', compact('menus', 'user'));` If you can edit it for someone other who will look this forum for help.

Comment: I missed that one.. Edited the Answer and added the bracket...